# dynamically expanding array of struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I am (trying to) write a server-side daemon in c, and it accepts connections from clients. I need a struct that keeps information on each open connection, so I have created an array of my defined struct, and I have it dynamically re-sizing with realloc.

The problem I have is creating the struct within the array.  I keep getting this error:

```
test.c:41: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

What am I doing wrong?

I spend most of my time in PHP, and am a noob with c. I realize that I am making some simple, beginner mistakes (in other words, feel free to make fun of me). If I am doing something stupid, please let me know.  I've put my quality time in with google, but have not figured it out.  I have reproduced the issue on smaller scale, as below:

here is my test.h:

```
typedef struct test_ test;
```

and here is my test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "test.h"

//define the struct
struct test_ {
    int id;
    char *ip;
    int user;
    char *str;
};

//yes, the list needs to be global
test *test_list;


//
// add an item to the global list
//
int add(int id, char *ip, int size)
{
    //
    // increment size
    if(id>size) {
        size = id;
        //try to expand the list
        test *tmp = realloc(test_list,size);
        if(tmp) {
            //it worked; copy list back
            test_list = tmp;
        } else {
            //out of memory
            printf("could now expand list\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    //
    // HERE IS THE TROUBLE CODE::
    test_list[id] = (struct test)malloc(sizeof(test)+(sizeof(int)*5)+strlen(ip)+1);
    test_list[id].id = id;
    test_list[id].ip = malloc(strlen(ip));
        strcpy(test_list[id].ip,ip);
    test_list[id].user = 0;
    test_list[id].str = NULL;
}

//
// main
//
int main(void)
{
    //initialize
    int size = 1;
    test_list = malloc(size*sizeof(test));
    //add 10 dummy items
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        size = add(i, "sample-ip-addr", size);
    }
    //that's it!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
test *tmp = realloc(test_list,size);
```

to

```
test *tmp = realloc(test_list,size*sizeof(test));
```

then delete

```
test_list[id] = (struct test)malloc(sizeof(test)+(sizeof(int)*5)+strlen(ip)+1);
```

When you allocate for test_list, there's already space for each member of the struct allocated, so you don't need to do it again. You just have to allocate for any pointers within the struct

Comment: that did the trick! (almost):
I also modified the next few lines into
`
 test *x = &test_list[id];
 x->id = id;
 x->ip = malloc(strlen(ip));
  strcpy(x->ip,ip);
 x->user = 0;
 x->str = NULL;
`
And I get:
`*** glibc detected *** ./test: realloc(): invalid next size: ...`
after a few iterations in my for loop

In any case, I gave you the points (you answered my initial question).

Answer (score 0):

The return value from 'malloc' is the memory address you've allocated. You can't cast it to a struct. What would that even mean?

You want something like: test_list=realloc(test_list, num_alloc * sizeof(test_));